# What is the difference between the intervals

Tags: real-analysis

What is the difference between the intervals $(-1, 1)$ and $[-k,k], |k|<1$. 
To me both represents the collection of all real numbers between $-1$ and $1$, ofcourse excluding $-1$ and $1$. Am I missing something? I am confused because of the following line in my book.

.... since the radius of convergence of the power series is 1, therefore the series is absolutely convergent in $(-1, 1)$ and uniformly convergent in $[-k,k], |k|<1$.

Can not we write it as : The power series is absolutely and uniformly convergent in $(-1, 1)$ ? As union of $[-k,k], |k|<1$ is $(-1, 1)$, so cannot we replace $[-k,k], |k|<1$ by $(-1, 1)$ in this particular case?

Comment: If $\lvert k\rvert<1$, then $[-k,k]$ is the empty set if $k<0$ and the set $\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, -k\le x\wedge x\le k\}$ if $k\ge 0$. The collection of such intervals is a subset $H$ of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, the set of subsets of $\Bbb R$. The *union* of the aforementioned set of subsets $H$ is $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is a fixed number, then $[-k,k]$ just contains numbers that are smaller than $k$ when $k$ is positive.

I think you intend to write

$$\bigcup_{0<k<1}[-k,k]=(-1,1)$$

Answer (score 0):

First off, does $[-k, k]$ mean anything when $-1<k<0$? Maybe you want to consider changing $|k| < 1$ to $0\leq k<1$? Or perhaps you see $[-0.5,0.5]$ as equal to $[0.5,-0.5]$? I wouldn't be surprised if some do, but I don't; to me the latter is either meaningless or empty.

$(-1, 1)$ is an open interval of width $2$, while $[-k, k]$ other is a closed interval of width $2k$.

If you meant to vary the $k$, then what you have on the right side is a *collection of closed intervals*.

If you want them to be the same, then you should say what to *do* with this collection of intervals to make them even comparable (an interval and a collection of intervals is not directly comparable using $=$). For instance, I recommend using union:
$$
(-1, 1) = \bigcup_{k\in [0,1)}[-k, k]
$$
which is true, and what I guess you really meant. In other words, when seen together, the collection of all the different $[-k, k]$ we consider covers the same part of the real line as $(-1, 1)$.